# How to make resolver work with ngrx store

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have following routing configuration.

It's all about selecting items from kendo-grid list and displays details next to it. When user selects more than one, or doest select anything. It should display 'EmptyStateComponent' - u can see it on first screen. And it works, as Im able to display all the data in this component. But the problem is it only fires once, and I need to collect array of ID's every time when selection on the grid changes and display how many items are selected in message(you can see it on the last screen). Unforunantly I can't get rid of take(1) opearator in resolver, becasuse entire module stop working then (resolver does not allow to enter probably)

The situation now is following: [image] It only displays that two items are selected, and when I select more I doest not refresh. What is wrong ?

**Routing:**
[image]

**Resolver**
[image]

**Comonent that should take date from resolver**
[image]

Code :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [RedirectGuard, ConvertersRootGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    component: ConvertersGroupComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: `:${CONVERTERS_GROUPS_ROUTER_DETAILS_KEY}`,
        canActivate: [ConverterGroupsDetailsGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./converters-groups-details/converters-groups-details.module').then((m) => m.ConverterGroupsDetailsModule),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: EmptyStateComponent,
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
        resolve: {
          data: GroupResolver,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

@Injectable()
export class GroupResolver implements Resolve<Observable<EmptyState>> {
  constructor(private readonly store$: Store) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<EmptyState> {
    return this.store$.select(selectors.getAllSelectedIDs).pipe(
      take(1),
      map((ids: ID[]) => {
        const data = {
          svg: ''
          message: !ids.length
            ? 'To see additional information, please select element from the list'
            : 'Use toolbar to perform desired actions for selected Items',
          header: `Selected groups: ${Dids.length}`,
        };

        return data;
      })
    );





  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'lib-core-empty',
  templateUrl: './empty.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empty.component.scss'],
})
export class EmptyStateComponent {
  @Input() public svg = '';
  @Input() public header = '';
  @Input() public message = '';

  @ViewChild('svg') public svgEl!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const resolvedData = this.route.snapshot.data['data'] as EmptyStateComponent;

      
    
    this.svg = resolvedData?.svg ?? '';
    this.header = resolvedData?.header ?? '';
    this.message = resolvedData?.message ?? '';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.svgEl.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.svg ?? '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bartek, can you provide your code as a code, not as screenshots?